# Converting Oracle Dates

Tags: oracle, date

I'm having the most difficult time with dealing with dates in Oracle. I find myself spending literal hours attempting to get queries to compile and run due to issues with dates. I don't understand how this is suppose to be useful.

I have a text field 4/23/2015 as a date.  I need to convert this date into two forms; 4/2015 and 04/23/2015.  I have figured out how to convert to both types through the use of TO_CHAR and TO_DATE, but my results seem inconsistent.

When I attempt to convert to MM/YYYY format, I get this failure: ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

```
TO_DATE(hist.DATESTAMP, 'MM/YYYY')
```

If I change this to `TO_CHAR(hist.DATESTAMP, 'MM/YYYY')` it works as expected, but now the query to show items after a given date no longer works as it is now a string and not a date.  `WHERE DATESTAMP > '04/01/2015'`

I have a large csv file which I imported the data into an Oracle table and need to provide reporting on it.

I need the results to be searchable on the date, and the report to display just the month and year.  There are totals which are combine, via the group by, to show total during the month.

In SQL Server, I can easily accomplish this task.  However, Oracle is a royal pain when dealing with dates and I'm at a loss how to make this work correctly.

I have been reading every source I can find on dates, especially here. And in a vacuum of a select via dual, I can convert a string to a date and that date into my month/year string.  But my active imported table continues to toss error after error around dates.

I could use some real guidance.  Thank you

Table and script for the curious

```
CREATE TABLE MONTHLY_DATA
(
  ID                     NUMBER(10)             NOT NULL,
  DATESTAMP              DATE                   NOT NULL,
  PARTNER                VARCHAR2(256 BYTE)     NOT NULL,
  APPNAME                VARCHAR2(256 BYTE)     NOT NULL,
  TYPE_NAME              VARCHAR2(256 BYTE)     NOT NULL,
  PLATFORM               VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)      NOT NULL, -- RED or BLUE
  VOLUME                 NUMBER(10)             NOT NULL,
  LBSSUMMARY             VARCHAR2(5 BYTE)       NOT NULL, -- TRUE or FALSE
  CREATE_DTS             DATE,
  MODIFIED_DTS           DATE,
  LAST_MODIFIED_USER     VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)
)


CREATE TABLE MONTHLY_SUMMARY
(
  DATESTAMP           DATE                      NOT NULL,
  RED_VOLUME          NUMBER(10)                NOT NULL,
  BLUE_VOLUME         NUMBER(10)                NOT NULL,
  LBS_VOLUME          NUMBER(10)                NOT NULL,
  CREATE_DTS          DATE,
  MODIFIED_DTS        DATE,
  LAST_MODIFIED_USER  VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)
)
```

The data in MONTHLY_DATA has ~50k rows a month.
The goal is to summarize this data, and provide an overall volume.

Also, NLS is set as:
    select * from nls_session_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';             NLS_DATE_FORMAT: DD-MON-RR

The value for MONTHLY_SUMMARY grouped for the month. Each month should have only 1 row;

> 03/2015 52 77 19
>
> 04/2015 34 76 21

Both tables are used to build reports using the date. Making the where clause simple; such as described above is what
I'm after.  WHERE DATESTAMP > '04/01/2015', however it seems I need to convert using TO_DATE.

This is the script for loading the data.

```
   INSERT INTO MONTHLY_SUMMARY (DATESTAMP, RED_VOLUME, BLUE_VOLUME, LBS_VOLUME)
   SELECT DISTINCT
          MONTHLY_DATA.DATESTAMP,
          CASE WHEN red.VOLUME IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE red.VOLUME END AS RED_VOLUME,
          CASE WHEN blue.VOLUME IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE blue.VOLUME END AS BLUE_VOLUME,
          CASE WHEN lbs.VOLUME IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE lbs.VOLUME END AS LBS_VOLUME
   FROM MONTHLY_DATA hist
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATESTAMP, SUM(hist.VOLUME) AS VOLUME
              FROM MONTHLY_DATA md
              WHERE PLATFORM = 'RED'
              GROUP BY DATESTAMP) red
          ON md.DATESTAMP = red.DATESTAMP
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATESTAMP, SUM(hist.VOLUME) AS VOLUME
              FROM MONTHLY_DATA md
              WHERE PLATFORM = 'BLUE'
              GROUP BY DATESTAMP) blue
          ON md.DATESTAMP = blue.DATESTAMP
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATESTAMP, SUM(MONTHLY_DATA.VOLUME) AS VOLUME
              FROM MONTHLY_DATA
              WHERE LBSSUMMARY = 'TRUE' 
              GROUP BY DATESTAMP) lbs
          ON MONTHLY_DATA.DATESTAMP = lbs.DATESTAMP
   WHERE MONTHLY_DATA.DATESTAMP 
     NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT DATESTAMP FROM MONTHLY_SUMMARY)
   GROUP BY 
         MONTHLY_DATA.DATESTAMP,
         red.VOLUME,
         blue.VOLUME,
         lbs.VOLUME
   ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Are you starting with a clean table where all dates are valid?

You want to avoid the situation where you stored imported dates into the database table as strings. If some of those strings are invalid, it will fail at the moment you try to convert them on the fly during a query.

Before you go further, best to complete the data cleansing exercise of storing all dates in a column of type DATE within the table.

Let us know if you have already got this far?

Comment: Yes, the column have been validated and contains correctly formatted dates.

Comment: I would prefer to save the dates as a DATE datatype. But the conversion only appears to partially work when I turn it into a string.

Comment: The problem is you are storing dates as text. Every problem you discuss here stems from that. In addition you have the data in a bad sequence as well. YYYY-MM-DD  OR YYYYMMDD  would be better but still not as good as date.

Comment: My import, from csv, into my source table, successfully moves into a DATE column.  I do this with the following code TO_DATE(rawdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY') which matches the format of the date string in the csv.
From here, I'm able to get a year and or a month and perform work against that data.
Now, I'm building a summary table to get a total count by month. 
So far, the only way I've been able to accomplish this task is to use TO_CHAR, but that converts to a varchar string. I would prefer this as a date, to allow easy queries. Instead, I have a where clause that is more complex.

Comment: `to_char()` converts a **`DATE`** to a varchar/string. And if you do store the dates in a `DATE` column there is absolutely no need to apply either `to_date()` or `to_char()` on them for comparison. Just use `DATESTAMP > date '2015-04-01'`

Comment: "*I would prefer this as a date, to allow easy queries. Instead, I have a where clause that is more complex*". please add some sample data, the expected results based on that data and the **complete** queries you were trying. This sounds like an entirely different questions: "how do I properly *compare* dates in Oracle" - not "how to *convert* a string to a date"

Comment: Updated to include table and script.

Comment: Thanks for the table definitions. That helped to get a better idea of what's going on.

I'd be tempted to use two fields, summary_year and summary_month (both integers), as the primary key for monthly summary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Converting strings/varchar values to dates

Now once you have that you need to properly convert your dates.

> *TO_DATE(hist.DATESTAMP, 'MM/YYYY')*

The above is wrong because your date is stored as `'dd/mm/yyy'` so converting a varchar value like `4/23/2015` into a proper date using the format mask `mm/yyyy` will not work. You need to provide a format mask that matches your input. You **have** to use `TO_DATE(hist.DATESTAMP, 'dd/MM/YYYY')`

> *If I change this to TO_CHAR(hist.DATESTAMP, 'MM/YYYY') it works as expected*

This does not "work as expected", because `to_char()` converts a `DATE` value to a string/varchar value. But you are passing a `varchar` value to the function which first gets *implicitly* converted to a date in order to make the function call work. This conversion depends on the locale (NLS) settings of the *client* running that statement. On my computer your query would fail because my default date format is different.

If you want to display your string in a different format, you *first* have to convert it properly to a date, *then* convert that date back to string:

```
to_char(TO_DATE(hist.DATESTAMP, 'dd/MM/YYYY'), 'mm/yyyy')
```

If you had stored the date correctly as a `DATE` to_char((hist.DATESTAMP, 'mm/yyyy')` would be enough.

If you want to use a "date" condition on your string value you **have** to first convert the string value to a proper date:

```
WHERE to_date(DATESTAMP, 'mm/dd/yyyy') > to_date('04/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

This is now comparing a date to a date. `WHERE DATESTAMP > '04/01/2015'` is comparing a string to a string. And because of the format `mm/dd/yyyy` this is not going to work correctly. If you really want to store and compare strings, you should at least store them in a format that can be compare properly, e.g. `yyyy-mm-dd`

For a date *constant* I prefer to use the short and un-ambigous ANSI date literals:

```
WHERE to_date(DATESTAMP, 'mm/dd/yyyy') > DATE '2015-04-01'
```

---

## Comparing date values in Oracle

If the column is indeed a `date` (as your comments seem to indicate now), then all you need to do is:

```
WHERE DATESTAMP > DATE '2015-04-01'
```

or if you just want to check for a specific month and year combination:

```
where extract(year from datestamp) = 2015
  and extract(month from datestamp) = 4
```

or

```
where (extract(year from datestamp), extract(month from datestamp)) = ((2015,4))
```

alternatively this can indeed be done using string comparison:

```
where to_char(datestamp, 'yyyy-mm') = '2015-04'
```

Or if you prefer a query that can make use of an index on the `datestamp` column

```
where datestamp >= date '2015-04-01'  
  and datestamp < date '2015-05-01'
```

---

<sup>The only **really** annoying thing about dates in Oracle is that they always contain a time part. And it seems to me that Oracle has no interest in fixing that e.g. by introducing a new `DATE2` type or something similar.</sup>

Comment: Why having time in date is the problem ?

Comment: @igr: because if you don't need it you still have to deal with it. e.g. `current_date` also returns date **and** time. Things like `where some_date_column = current_date` usually don't return anything because of the time part in the column and the current_date

Comment: For that last mentioned issue using TRUNC(datecolumn)  sets time at midnight. You may also use that function for calendar units e.g. month.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that should not be the problem if you do not use time (at all, on both sizes, consistently. So if you store just date, read just date, compare just date it should be ok. Only thing to keep in mind is to have appropriate correct default format for display and implicit conversion, and use explicit format just as exception. I find problematic approaches where time is completely independent of date...

Answer (score 0):

After much wheel spinning and trying everything, I believe I have found the crux of my misunderstanding.  The TO_DATE and TO_CHAR methods require the NLS Format for the date.  If you attempt to use a different format, you run the likely risk of an error.

Once I converted the initial format to DD-MON-RR, all the pieces started working correctly.  I was also able to perform date filters with the where clause, which previously were causing issues.

Thank you for all the assistance and support. I think I'm on the right road, finally.